Difference between Train AUC and Test AUC in MaxEnt
I would like a clear explanation of the difference between the train AUC and test AUC in MaxEnt. How is it calculated based on my input data? Is it the train AUC that is the average of X iterations, or is it the test AUC? Does it use a number of my presences in multiple random groups, or does it test areas of my MaxEnt model randomly? I’m confused... Please help me better understand the origin of the indicators I’m using.
